# New JVM or Process per Tab

Tags: java, jvm

**The Problem:**

I have a JTabbedPane that spawns "Clients". Each client is an instance of an applet loaded from a jar file using a URLClassLoader. So basically, each Tab contains a game applet.

Every time a tab spawns, task manager shows that the amount of memory in use is increased. Which is fine. However, when a tab closes, the applet is stopped and destroyed but the memory usage according to task manager is still the same.

I tried calling System.gc which isn't guaranteed and that does nothing at all! I tried nulling all references to the applet but that does nothing as well.

**My Solution if possible:**

Every tab has its own JVM/Process that runs the game. When a Tab is closed, the applet will stop, destroy, and the memory used by the process/JVM will be given back to the OS because the process/JVM is dead?

How can I do such a thing? Is it possible to have each Tab in my JTabbedPane run the Jar or create a new JVM to run it in?

If not, how can I clear the memory of all the tabs closed?

Comment: Giving each tab its own JVM sounds like unnecessary complexity. Maybe you have a memory leak, maybe you don't. There's no guarantee that JVM-per-tab would actually solve that. How about first verifying that you do _actually_ have a memory leak, and then finding it, and fixing it?

Comment: A JVM-per-tab sounds pretty nuts to me: are you sure you're solving a problem that actually exists?

Comment: But I did verify. There is no leak :S I closed all files, all URLClassLoaders, everything before calling stop and destroy.. I nulled ALL reference after that. Yet still as long as the Frame is on screen, the memory is still in use :S. I used netbeans profiler. As soon as I close a tab and press the netbeans GC button, the memory usage is gone.. I do this manually in my application, doesn't work.

Comment: That's not a leak, that's a the-memory-wasn't-reclaimed. And why an applet, anyway?

Comment: Because the game is an applet. I didn't make the game. I only made a loader for it so that I don't have to play it in the browser all the time. Why is it nuts :S Doesn't google chrome launch each tab as a process?

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames Chrome isn't a Swing app. It's nuts because it's unlikely there's any *need* to spawn a JVM-per-tab within a single application, and if it's actually a leak, you'd still have the leak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First, use the right tool for the job. Process Manager doesn't know
       anything about the JVM, which manages it's own memory. Download the
       latest version of VisualVM and install the VisualGC plugin. Examine
       what is actually happening rather than guessing with Process
       Manager. If you are indeed not collecting your memory back, use the
       memory profiler in VisualVM or a tool like Plumbr.
2. Don't worry about memory, unless you step #1 reveals a memory leak :) If you're on a memory constrained system, set an appropriate Xmx value. Also, the newest Oracle JRE includes a G1GC garbage collector option. This GC will reduce the heap size automatically when your application no longer requires a large heap. Try running your app with (at least) these options:

   - -XX:+UseAdaptiveSizePolicy
   - -XX:+UseAdaptiveGCBoundary
   - -XX:+UseCompressedOops
   - -XX:+UseG1GC

Good luck!

Comment: None of which helped but I'll accept this anyway I guess.. That profiler doesn't show any leaks or anything wrong with it. I'll have to figure out how to spawn a JVM on my own then.

Comment: Did you try the JVM options? They should cause the JVM to release the memory to the operating system after a few GCs of not needing the extra memory.

Comment: Tried each and every one of those separate and combined and verbosed:

http://pastebin.com/7M2mam1D

Still nothing.. :l Thanks for the response.

Comment: strange... what is the output from `java -version` of the JRE you are using to run your program?

Comment: java version "1.7.0_21"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_21-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.21-b01, mixed mode)

Comment: I can start Eclipse with these options and go from a 32mb to 500mb then down to a 180mb total heap size. Side note: I think your problem here may be more mental than programmatic :/ If you are sure you don't have a memory leak and you're on the newest JVM, you are probably just fine.